# How does AirBnb create a collection view with different cells?

Tags: ios, layout

I noticed in the Airbnb app when you click on a specific cell on the home screen, they have a complex collection view displaying various items in different looking collection view cells. I have attached 4 pics below:

[image][image][image][image]

In those pictures you have different sections like `About your host`, `Availability`, `Reviews`, `Group size up to 2 guests`, `Guest requirement`, `Contact Host`, etc. How does one go about organizing a view like this?

Is this just a bunch of different cells in a TableView or CollectionView? Since every single item I click on the home screen has a very similar layout with the exact same sections. Or are these just views placed on a scrollview?

Comment: If you want to be 100% sure, you can use Reveal on a jb device: http://marksands.github.io/2014/01/03/inspecting-third-party-apps.html Or without jb: https://github.com/Naituw/IPAPatch

Comment: Just looks like a `UITableView` to me. What makes you think it is a `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 0):

It's *probably* a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` with a set of different cells. So their `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` functions would return a different cell class for each different section.

They'll have an `AboutYourHostCell` class, an `AvailabilityCell` class, a `ReviewsCell` class, etc.

It would be possible to do this by adding Views into a `UIScrollView`, but it would be a lot of work, and you'd lose some nice behaviour that `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` provides - like highlighting cells when you press and hold, and animating changes.